# I get an error when using Mailkit to send a Gmail email

Tags: gmail, mailkit

I am trying a simple Mailkit set up in Visual Studio App with C#.  Have got an App Password and created the mimemessage. However when I create the SmtpClient and send:
`SmtpClient smtpClient = new();

```
    try
    {
        smtpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com",465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
        smtpClient.Authenticate("gdtmailkit@gmail.com", "**App Password**");
        smtpClient.Send(message);

        messageText.Text = "Message Sent";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        messageText.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        smtpClient.Disconnect(true);
        smtpClient.Dispose();
    }`
```

I get the following error, on the smtpClient.Connect line, which I unfortunately don't understand:
An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
• The certificate's revocation status could not be determined.
• An intermediate certificate has the following errors:
• Unable to determine revocation status due to network error

Appreciate any help.
** Note, the error is only raised when running on Android (Emulator and Local Device).No issue when running in Windows.  Not tested Ios.

I have tried different gmail addresses without success, bit the error seems to be on the client connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the Certificate Revocation server was probably offline (or otherwise unreachable), and so the client was unable to check whether the certificate has been revoked or not.

This is just how SSL works and is the only way that it can assure authenticity of the server.

You can bypass the revocation check by setting the following property before trying to connect:

```
smtpClient.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
```